# SQL query for duplicate customers

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want number of customers (count) and duplicate `phone_no` from a table. I have to remove dashes in phone number and then check the length is equal to 10. Please can anyone help with this SQL query?

My query is like below :

```
select 
    COUNT(Cust_ID) cnt, Phone_no 
from 
    tbl_Customers 
where 
    Cust_Type = 3
group by 
    Phone_no
having 
    COUNT(Cust_ID) > 1 
order by 
    cnt desc
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: Count and duplicate phone_no. My real problem is, how I can remove dashes and take length of phone_no in where condition?.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `LEN(REPLACE(Phone_no,'-','')) = 10` in your `WHERE` clause should be what your looking for.

```
select COUNT(Cust_ID) cnt,Phone_no 
from tbl_Customers 
where Cust_Type = 3
      and
      LEN(REPLACE(Phone_no,'-','')) = 10
group by Phone_no
having COUNT(Cust_ID) > 1 
order by cnt desc
```

Here is the Microsoft documentation for those functions.

[REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql)

[LEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql)